How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^n\frac{(1-\cos\left( \frac tn\right)) \ln \left( 1+\frac tn\right)}{\left( \frac tn\right)^{3} (1+t^2)} dt$
I’m sorry, I haven’t used $\tt MathJax$ before and I’m not familiar with the code: I’m worried the code might be incorrect, so I attached an image of the problem
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}
\frac{\left[1 - \cos\left(t/n\right)\right]
\ln\left(1 + t/n\right)}{\left(t/n\right)^{3} (1 + t^{2})}\,{\rm d}t
$$
enter image description here

I tried to split the integration interval and sum with a step size of $1$, but it seems that I can't solve the problem this way.
I also tried using the mean value theorem for integrals, but still couldn't solve the problem, so I would like to ask for everyone's help.

Thank you all.

Are you familiar with Taylor expansion?

Any chance you see a good substitution to perform on the integral?

Yes, I am very familiar with the Taylor series

thank you all! I have solved it by dirac's delta function. We can make the substitution u=t/n,then pin/(1+（n^2)(x^2)) can be regard as a delta function ,then the problem can be solved easily. thank you all!

@QQmoon you can write it in an answer

@Sine of the Time but i can't wirte mathjax code,sry

Too long for a comment
$$I(n)=\int_0^n\frac{(1-\cos\left( \frac tn\right)) \ln \left( 1+\frac tn\right)}{\left( \frac tn\right)^3 (1+t^2)} dt=2\int_0^n\frac{\sin^2(\frac t{2n})\, \ln \left( 1+\frac tn\right)}{\left( \frac tn\right)^3 (1+t^2)} dt$$
Note that
$$\ln \left( 1+\frac tn\right)\leqslant\frac tn\,\, \text{and}\,\,\sin\Big(\frac t{2n}\Big)\leqslant\frac t{2n}\,\,\text{at}\,\,t\in[0;n]$$
Indeed, the logarithm and $\sin$ are growing functions on this interval, and
$$\ln \left( 1+\frac tn\right)=\frac tn=0\,\,\text{at}\,\, t=0\,\,\text{and}\,\,\ln' \left( 1+\frac tn\right)=\frac1{t+n}\leqslant\left( \frac tn\right)'=\frac 1n$$
$$\sin \Big(\frac t{2n}\Big)=\frac t{2n}=0\,\,\text{at}\,\, t=0\,\,\text{and}\,\,\sin' \Big(\frac t{2n}\Big)=\frac1{2n}\cos\Big(\frac t{2n}\Big)\leqslant\left( \frac t{2n}\right)'=\frac 1{2n}$$
Therefore, we can introduce the set of the functions
$$f_n(t)=2\frac{\sin^2(\frac t{2n})\, \ln \left( 1+\frac tn\right)}{\left( \frac tn\right)^3 (1+t^2)}\bf{\chi}_{[0;n]}$$
which is majorized on the interval $[0;\infty)$ by the integrable function
$\displaystyle f(t)=2\frac{\big(\frac t{2n}\big)^2\,\left( \frac tn\right)}{\left( \frac tn\right)^3 (1+t^2)}=\frac12\frac1{1+t^2}$
$$I(n)=\int_0^\infty f_n(t)dt=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2(\frac t{2n})\, \ln \left( 1+\frac tn\right)}{\left( \frac tn\right)^3 (1+t^2)}\chi_{[0;n]}dt\leqslant\int_0^\infty f(t)dt$$
According to the dominated convergence theorem we are allowed to take the limit under the integral sign:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} I(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty f_n(t)dt=\int_0^\infty\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(t)dt=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\frac\pi4$$

thanks! I learned a lot from your answer!!

Thanks everyone's help! I found a better conclusion in my analysis textbook.
if $f\in C[0,1]$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f(x) \frac{n}{1 + (nx)^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2} f(0)$$
Here are proof:
$f\in C[0,1]$,so $\exists M>0,s.t.\forall x \in [0,1],\left |f(x)\right|\le M$
$\forall n\in N$,
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{nf(x)}{1+(nx)^{2}}dx=\int_{0}^{n^{-\frac{1}{3}}}\frac{nf(x)}{1+(nx)^{2}}dx+\int_{n^{-\frac{1}{3}}}^{1}\frac{nf(x)}{1+(nx)^{2}}dx$$
$$\left|\int_{n^{-\frac{1}{3}}}^{1}\frac{nf(x)}{1+(nx)^{2}}dx\right|\le\int_{n^{-\frac{1}{3}}}^{1}\left|\frac{nf(x)}{1+(nx)^{2}}\right|dx$$
$$\le \frac{nM}{1+n^{1+\frac{1}{3}}}\to0 (n\to\infty)$$
as for$$\int_{0}^{n^{-\frac{1}{3}}}\frac{nf(x)}{1+(nx)^{2}}dx$$
we know$\frac{n}{1+(nx)^{2}}$ keeps positive.
According to the Mean Value Theorem for definite integrals$\exists \xi\in[0,n^{-\frac{1}{3}}]$
s.t.
$$\int_{0}^{n^{-\frac{1}{3}}}\frac{nf(x)}{1+(nx)^{2}}dx=f(\xi)\int_{0}^{n^{-\frac{1}{3}}}\frac{n}{1+(nx)^{2}}dx$$
$$=f(\xi)\arctan{n^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$
snd
$$\xi \to 0(n\to\infty)$$
beacuse$\xi \in [0,n^{-\frac{1}{3}}]$
and
$$\arctan{n^{\frac{2}{3}}}\to\frac{\pi}{2}(n\to\infty)$$
so
$$\int_{0}^{n^{-\frac{1}{3}}}\frac{nf(x)}{1+(nx)^{2}}dx\to \frac{\pi}{2}f(0)$$
and
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f(x) \frac{n}{1 + (nx)^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2} f(0)$$
and this conclusion can be used in the original question successfully.
Thank you everyone!

Nice technique. +1 The exponent $1/3$ in $n^{-1/3}$ can be any positive number less than $1/2$.

Let the integral under limit be denoted by $I_n$ and we make a substitution $t=nx$ to get $$I_n=n\int_0^1\frac{(1-\cos x) \log(1+x)} {x^3(1+n^2x^2)}\,dx\tag{1}$$ Let us split the range of integration into $[0,h]$ and $[h, 1]$ where $h$ is any arbitrary number in $(0,1)$. Accordingly the expression $I_n$ splits into two parts as $I_n=A_n+B_n$ where $B_n$ is bounded above by $$\frac{n}{2}\int_h^1\frac{x^2\cdot x} {x^3\cdot n^2x^2}\,dx=\frac{2}{n}\int_h^1\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{2}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{h}\right)$$ Here we have used the inequalities $$1-\cos x\leq \frac{x^2}{2},\log(1+x)\leq x$$ The other term $A_n$ requires more analysis and we have using the same inequalities above $$0<A_n<\frac{n}{2}\int_0^h\frac{dx}{1+n^2x^2}$$ ie $$0<A_n<\frac{1}{2}\cdot\arctan (nh)$$ and hence $$I_n<\frac{1}{2}\cdot\arctan (nh)+\frac{2}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{h}\right)$$ Taking limits as $n\to\infty$ we get $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} I_n\leq \frac{\pi} {4}\tag{2}$$ Next we need to bound $A_n, B_n$ from below and thus find a lower bound for $\liminf_{n\to\infty} I_n$. For $B_n$ we just note that $B_n>0$. To handle $A_n$ we use the inequalities $$1-\cos x \geq \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{24}$$ and $$\log (1+x)\geq x-\frac{x^2}{2}$$ and thus $$A_n\geq \frac{n} {2}\int_0^h\frac{(1-x^2/12)(1-x/2)}{1+n^2x^2}\,dx$$ or $$A_n\geq \frac{n} {2}\int_0^h\frac{dx}{1+n^2x^2}-\frac{n}{4}\int_0^h\frac{x+x^2/6-x^3/12}{1+n^2x^2}\,dx$$ The second term above can be easily handled by noting that numerator in the integral above can be written as $x\cdot(1+x/6-x^2/12) $ and this does not exceed $3x/2$ for all sufficiently small values of $x$ and thus the term does not exceed $$\frac{3h} {8}\arctan(nh)$$ so that $$I_n=A_n+B_n>A_n\geq \frac{1}{2}\arctan(nh)-\frac{3h}{8}\arctan(nh)$$ Taking limits as $n\to\infty$ we get $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} I_n\geq \frac{\pi} {4}-\frac{3\pi h}{16}$$ The above inequality holds for all sufficiently small values of $h\in(0,1)$ and hence taking $h\to 0^+$ we get $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} I_n\geq \frac{\pi} {4}\tag{3}$$ From $(2),(3)$ we see that $I_n\to \pi/4$.

thank you so much!!

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}
{\bracks{1 - \cos\pars{t/n}}
\ln\pars{1 + t/n} \over \pars{t/n}^{3}\pars{1 + t^{2}}}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] \sr{t/n\ \mapsto\ t}{=} & 
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{n\int_{0}^{1}
{\bracks{1 - \cos\pars{t}}
\ln\pars{1 + t} \over t^{3}\pars{1 + n^{2}t^{2}}}
\,\dd t}
\end{align}
The main contribution to the integral, as $\ds{n \to \infty}$, comes from a neighborhood of $\ds{t = 0}$.
Therefore,
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{n}
{\bracks{1 - \cos\pars{t/n}}
\ln\pars{1 + t/n} \over \pars{t/n}^{3}\pars{1 + t^{2}}}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] = & \
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{n\int_{0}^{1}
{\pars{t^{2}/2}\pars{t} \over t^{3}}{1 \over 1 + n^{2}t^{2}}\dd t}
\\[5mm] = & \ {1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over 1 + t^{2}} = \bbx{\color{#44f}{\pi \over 4}} \approx
0.7854
\end{align}

thanks for your help :)
